# Rationale behind loading all cache data in RoboSpice's Persistor?

Tags: android, robospice

Writing a custom `Persistor` for saving a certain types of data object , one needs to extend [`ObjectPersistor`](http://stephanenicolas.github.com/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/index.html?com/octo/android/robospice/persistence/ObjectPersister.html) of [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki).

What is the reason behind these two methods required to implement?

```
@Override
public List<T> loadAllDataFromCache() throws CacheLoadingException {

}

@Override
public List<Object> getAllCacheKeys() {

}
```

A disk cache or any undelying Object store, can be HUGE. Why RoboSpice wants to load all data in memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the call hierarchy, you will find that `loadAllDataFromCache()` is indirectly used only by `com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager#getAllDataFromCache`.
For `getAllCacheKeys()`, it is similar - there is `com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager#getAllCacheKeys` utilizing it.

This means that you will probably be well off by implementing these methods to just throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. You should also consider overriding `SpiceManager`'s methods by the same logic.